# AWS-Device Farm: remotely trigger AWS device farm script and send parameter to the same

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, testing, appium, aws-device-farm

AWS-Device Farm: Need to setup a monitoring system using AWS where I can use an api to trigger a script. The script should be able to receive input from the trigger as well for execution. Can anyone please assist me with this.

Will setting it up in Jenkins help?

Answer (score 1):

What about a CloudWatch rule that invokes a lambda function?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html

What's the goal?

There is a Jenkins plugin for DFarm.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-jenkins-plugin